# Slow updates with updating rows in database with preparedStatement

Tags: java, beginner, sql

I have been shifting all of my SQL queries to prepared statements in the past few weeks and all of the INSERT statements run extremely fast, however, UPDATE is taking an inordinate amount of time.  At present, I am adding to the prepared statement then sending.  Updating 20 records can take over two minutes sometimes.  Here is my code:

```
if (updatePhoneList.elements().size()>0) {
        LOGGER.info("Will process " + updatePhoneList.elements().size() + " records");
        Date startDate = new Date();
        try {
            String compiledQuery = "UPDATE CUSTDATA.CUST_CONTACT_INFO SET CBR = ?, LAST_UPDATED_TIME = SYSDATE "
            + "WHERE ORDER_ID = ? AND CUSTNUM = ?";
            PreparedStatement bulkInsertStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(compiledQuery);
            for(int arrayPos = 0; arrayPos <= updatePhoneList.elements().size() -1 ; arrayPos++) {
                currentCust = updatePhoneList.elements().get(arrayPos).prop("CUSTNUM").stringValue();
                currentPhone = updatePhoneList.elements().get(arrayPos).prop("CUSTPHONE").stringValue();
                bulkInsertStatement.setString(1, currentPhone);
                bulkInsertStatement.setString(2, currentCust);
                bulkInsertStatement.setString(3, outageId);

            }
            updatedRecords = bulkInsertStatement.executeBatch();
            bulkInsertStatement.close();
            Date endDate = new Date();
            long execTimeMSec = (endDate.getTime()-startDate.getTime());
            LOGGER.info("Returning success: " + success);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = false;
        }       
    }
```

When I wrote this , I had no indices, but indexed the CUST_CONTACT_INFO to index on ORDER_ID and CUSTNUM.  It runs markedly faster.

Comment: Is this UPDATE or INSERT code?  `updatePhoneList` suggests the former, but `bulkInsertStatement` the latter.  What is the SQL statement?  How is the table defined?  What keys, indexes, constraints are defined?  Just not enough detail here to answer.

Comment: You lament the performance of a `compiledQuery` without so much as showing it. Please add relevant parts of the schema (including indexes) and the *execution plan*, too.

Comment: Your changes are a step in the right direction, but I don't think all comments have been addressed.